# Regex for grep special block of string?

Tags: php, regex, string, block

```
Info:  DVB:  =========== Card 0 - Tuner 0 ===========
Info:  DVB:   Frontend : Afatech AF9033 (DVB-T)
Info:  DVB:   Terrestrial (DVB-T) card
Info:  DVB:   Frequency: 174000 kHz to 862000 kHz
Info:  DVB:  
Info:  DVB:  =========== Card 1 - Tuner 0 ===========
Info:  DVB:   Frontend : Afatech AF9033 (DVB-T)
Info:  DVB:   Terrestrial (DVB-T) card
Info:  DVB:   Frequency: 174000 kHz to 862000 kHz
Info:  DVB:
```

`
how can i grep a special block of string? (e.g Card0 - Tuner 0 with any new line afte it to Card 1 - Tuner 0 )

Comment: You are grepping in PHP?

Comment: @chris85 yes...

Comment: Show your PHP usage.

Answer (score 1):

This may work:

```
preg_match_all("/(Info:.*Tuner 0.*)Info:  DVB:  $/ms", $String, $out);
var_dump($out[1]);
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/hYI

Comment: thanks...but why the regex returned two same element?

Comment: It doesn't. The first is the complete regex, both match and not matched parts.  The second is the match (the stuff inside the `()`). Note the last line is different.

Comment: @Rohullah do you find the answer correct? In that case it would be nice if you accepted the answer.

Comment: @RohullahRajaeeRad You have still not accepted the answer. Is it incorrect? Something that needs to be changed?